# org.apache.http.ContentTooLongException Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: org.apache.http.ContentTooLongException

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

```
Program type already present: org.apache.http.ContentTooLongException
```

`Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: org.apache.http.ContentTooLongException, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)
}`

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sample.io.sos"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.0'
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    dependencies {
        compileOnly 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.judemanutd:autostarter:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0"
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.7'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.10'
    annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.10'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

    implementation 'io.swagger:swagger-annotations:1.5.15'
    implementation 'io.gsonfire:gson-fire:1.8.0'
    implementation 'org.threeten:threetenbp:1.3.5'
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2"
    implementation "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.4"
    implementation "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.2"
    implementation "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3"
    implementation "com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0"
    testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0"
    testImplementation "net.jodah:concurrentunit:0.4.2"
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"
}
```

Can not solve this problem. Here i'm using swagger generated android java code in my project. That relevant implementations are added.

Comment: post complete error log

Comment: Sorry, Now I removed that swagger generated codes and files, because there are too many version compatibility issues in dependency libs., And reported to them. Currently i'm using normal retrofit for Api call integrations. Now every thing working good. Thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 0):

Swagger providing sdk for older version (compileSdkVersion 25). Still they didn't updated that sdk. But i want to developing for latest version 28. Also there are more version incompatible issues on that sdk. 
And i reported that problem in github.
[Swagger issues](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/8357)

Answer (score 0):

I am working for SDK version 22 and my comppiledsdk version is 27 .It gives me same error.Any pointers to share?

Gradle-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hp.mayukhapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false


            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'


    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
        compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
        compile 'com.sendgrid:sendgrid-java:4.0.1'

    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    compile group: 'com.pkmmte.view', name: 'circularimageview', version: '1.0'
    compile 'com.mostafagazar:customshapeimageview:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.pedroSG94.vlc-example-streamplayer:pedrovlc:2.5.14'
    implementation 'com.rvirin.onvif:onvifcamera:1.1.8'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
//    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
    // compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
   // compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```